# Issues with scipy minimize

Tags: python, numpy

I'm receiving the following error from scipy minimize.

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  inner = x[k]*((x[0]**int(cAnde[ses][sub][strats][0]))*(1.0-x[0])**int(cAnde[ses][sub][strats][1]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MLEestimation.py", line 39, in ,module.
     constraints=MLEfunction.MLEconstrain(x), method = 'SLSQP', options = {'disp': True})
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 458, in minimize
     constraints, callback=callback, **options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 370 in _minimize_slsqp
      raise ValueError("Objective function must return a scalar")
   ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar
```

But, when I check if the output of the objective function is a scalar using np.isscalar, I get that it is, so I'm uncertain of what I'm doing wrong. Below is all the code for reference.

```
import math
import pickle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import MLEfunction

x = [0.9,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.2]

def MLE(x, cAnde):
    est = 0.0
    for ses in cAnde:
        for sub in cAnde[ses]:
            k = 0
            for strats in cAnde[ses][sub]:
                k += 1
                inner = x[k] * x[0] ** int(cAnde[ses][sub][strats][0]) \
                    * (1.0 - x[0]) ** int(cAnde[ses][sub][strats][1])
                est += math.log(inner)
    est = -1.0 * est
    return est


def MLE_deriv(x, cAnde):
    der = np.zeros_like(x)
    d0 = 0
    for ses in cAnde:
        for sub in cAnde[ses]:
            for strat in cAnde[ses][sub]:
                inner = float(cAnde[ses][sub][strat][0]) / x[0]
                inner += float(cAnde[ses][sub][strat][1]) / (1 - x[0])
                d0 += inner
    der[0] = -1.0 * d0
    for k in range(len(x) - 1):
        d = 0
        for ses in cAnde:
            for sub in cAnde[ses]:
                d += 1.0 / x[k + 1]
        der[k + 1] = -1.0 * d
    return der


def MLEconstraint(x):
    cons = []
    jacs = []
    for j in range(len(x)):
        if j == 0:
            jacs.append(0.0)
        else:
            jacs.append(1.0)
    sum1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.array([sum(x[1:]) - 1]),
            'jac': lambda x: np.array(jacs)}
    cons.append(sum1)
    for k in range(len(x)):
        jacu = []
        jacd = []
        for l in range(len(x)):
            if l == k:
                jacu.append(-1.0)
                jacd.append(1.0)
            else:
                jacu.append(0.0)
                jacd.append(0.0)
        up = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.array([1 - x[k]]),
              'jac': lambda x: np.array(jacu)}
        low = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.array([x[k]]),
               'jac': lambda x: np.array(jacd)}
        cons.append(up)
        cons.append(low)
    return tuple(cons)


res = minimize(
    MLEfunction.MLE,
    x,
    args=CEs['48,0.75'],
    jac=MLEfunction.MLE_deriv,
    constraints=MLEfunction.MLEconstraint(x),
    method='SLSQP',
    options={'disp': True},
    )

print res.x
```

Note: the minimization is being done in a different .py file than the functions are defined, and I am importing the original file defining the functions

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error text, otherwise the question will become useless if the external image link breaks.

Comment: What is `MLEfunction`? Maybe you want to get rid of the `import` statement and all its usages in the definition of `res`? And what is `x`? And `CEs`?

Comment: MLEfunction is the python file where I store the three MLE functions. The optimizations was being done in a different .py file. x is an initial list of inputs that I forgot the include and edited in. CEs is a large dictionary file that I have stored as a pickle file and import

Comment: Without a working example it is hard to be certain but I would guess that inner becomes to big and hence returns nan. Could you check that?

Comment: No, inner never returns nan

Comment: I figured out the issue. inner would for some parameter inputs become 0 or negative, which is an issue since the function then takes the log of inner. That's been addressed and the function works fine now.